# Copy column from workbook to another and add comma for each cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying this to copy a column to another workbook. But I need to add a comma in each row. It is possible?

```
        WBSource.Worksheets(1).Columns(i).Copy _
        Destination:=WBDest.Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 ways to do it:

1. Iterate via each cell in the source, set the value of this cell to some variable, add a coma, and then set the value in destination cell of this variable.
2. Copy/paste the column, then iterate each cell in the resulting column to add comas.

I do the second one, much faster.

Also you can speed up all variant by disabling screen update while your macro works by adding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: Note that option 1 may very well have a 256 character limit.

Comment: I've tried your solution but I get double-quote, like this: "Myvalue1," "Myvalue2," etc... instead of : Myvalue1,Myvalue2,etc..

Comment: try getting/setting the cell value using cells(x,y).value or cells(x,y).formula, maybe this will help

Comment: @user359706 - when you build the string you have a quotation in the wrong place. = """" & data & """" & ","